# Scripted_upsert with Elasticsearch-hadoop impossible?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-hadoop

With the [Elasticsearch-hadoop](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html) Connector, is it possible to use the [scripted_upsert](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#scripted_upsert) to true on an upsert insertion ?

I am using the [es.update.script.inline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#cfg-update) configuration, but i can't find any way to use the script_upsert to true and to empty the contents of the upsert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since elastic-hadoop 8.2.0 , it is possible to use `scripted_upsert` with the parameter :

```
"es.update.script.upsert" -> "true"
```